# Setting User Input Restrictions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking for some advice again!

I'm making a simple program to calculate the square root of a given user input. I've managed that part.

I want to extend my learning now by placing a restriction on the user input. I want inputs to be 10 digits only, else it will ask to "try again".

I have managed to restrict it somewhat by placing maxlength as ten, but I am not sure how to make this my minlength too?

Here is my code, you can see what I was messing around with in my comments.

```js
function doMath(){
  
    var inputNum1 = document.form1.input1.value;
    var result = Math.sqrt(inputNum1);
    
    //if (inputNum1!\d{10}) {
    // "Enter a ten digit number";
    document.form1.answer.value = result;
    //}
    
}
```

```html
<form name=form1>
    Enter a ten-digit number:
    <input type="text" name="input1" size=16 maxlength=10><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick='doMath()'>
    <br><br>
    The square root is:
    <input type="text" name="answer" size=22>
</form>
```

Another detail, how do I stop the text from staying in the boxes after I refresh the screen? First time this has happened.

Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not see inputNum1 as a string?
Use inputNum.toString().length to solve this.

BESIDES, try to use autocomplete="off" on your < input >.

Comment: Just a question.. Is this concatenation actually gonna work?

var inputNum1 = document.form1.input1.value;

In pure javascript is that a thing that actually works?

Comment: I think getElementById is a better solution.

Comment: Thought so, wanted to know if that is actually a working method tho'. Cause that seems an error to me, but maybe I'm wrong and I don't know about it

Comment: Maybe some browsers can work like that. I tried firefox and IE,neither of them worked.

Comment: Thanks CY, I never thought about coverting to a string!

Comment: @mnemosdev the code works fine for me (except the input restriction), I was initially trying another method but I stuck with this. I'll try the other way too once I get this working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I got downvoted, maybe it seems trivial to more experienced members but we all have to start somewhere.

After some more tinkering I have a solution that works. It most likely isn't as elegant as what others can come up with but I will post some of the code to show how I got it to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function doMath(){

var inputNum1 = document.form1.input1.value;
var result = Math.sqrt(inputNum1);

    if(inputNum1.length == 10){


    document.form1.answer.value = result;

    }

    else {

        alert("Enter a ten digit number");
    }
}


function clear_field(field) {

        if (field.value==field.defaultValue) {

            field.value=''

        }

    }

</script>
```

As you can see, I also added a means of clearing data

```
</head>
<body>
<form name=form1>
Enter a ten-digit number:
<input type = "text" name = "input1" size = 12><br><br>
<input type = "button" value = "Calculate" onClick = 'doMath()'>
<br><br>
The square root is:
<input type = "text" name = "answer" size = 20>
    <br><br>
<input type = "reset" value = "Clear" onClick = 'clear_field(field)'>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully this will help someone else with a similar problem.And thanks again to those that offered help.